In a flyback, why does the Vin supply hit overcurrent protection mode if the PWM controller bias is turned on before it?
I am working with a DC-DC flyback converter with 60-325V Vin and 60V Vout. I'm using UCC2813-0 by TI as the PWM controller in the primary side. While powering on the flyback, I have to supply Vin first before I give the UCC2813-0 its voltage bias. If I power up the UCC before any other load/voltage supplies, then the Vin and load supplies go into some overcurrent protection mode when turned on. Why does this happen?

Does the soft start feature start ramping when you supply Vcc so it's already done and at max duty cycle by the time you supply Vin?

Have you tested the problematic circuit (flyback) by itself, away from any other sub-systems?  If yes, then how much current does it draw from its supply when there is maximum load connected, and supply voltage is set to minimum (eg: 60V)?   This start-up usually happens so fast that you will need a scope to view the current out of the supply.
